# Does anyone know how to simulate clicking enter button on my keyboard after i enter into a search field in Katalon

Tags: katalon-studio

This is my code

```
WebUI.openBrowser('')

WebUI.navigateToUrl('https://techcrunch.com/')

WebUI.click(findTestObject('Object Repository/newww/Page_TechCrunch  Startup and Technology News/div_Searchsearch'))

WebUI.setText(findTestObject('Object Repository/newww/Page_TechCrunch  Startup and Technology News/input_Close Search_p'), 
    'mobile')

WebUI.sendKeys(findTestObject('newww/Page_TechCrunch  Startup and Technology News/form_search'), ((Keys.ENTER) as String))

WebUI.closeBrowser()
```

I get this error
Test Cases/TestRecord FAILED.
Reason:
com.kms.katalon.core.exception.StepFailedException: Unable to send keys '' to object 'Object Repository/newww/Page_TechCrunch  Startup and Technology News/form_search'
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIKeywordMain.stepFailed(WebUIKeywordMain.groovy:64)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIKeywordMain.runKeyword(WebUIKeywordMain.groovy:26)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.SendKeysKeyword.sendKeys(SendKeysKeyword.groovy:60)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.SendKeysKeyword.execute(SendKeysKeyword.groovy:38)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordExecutor.executeKeywordForPlatform(KeywordExecutor.groovy:72)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords.sendKeys(WebUiBuiltInKeywords.groovy:834)
    at TestRecord.run(TestRecord:28)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:194)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:119)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:337)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:328)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:307)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:299)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:233)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:114)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:105)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$runTestCase$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at TempTestCase1579268178976.run(TempTestCase1579268178976.groovy:23)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.130)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'MiniMes-Mac-mini.local', ip: '192.168.0.101', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.5', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: com.kms.katalon.selenium.driver.CChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 79.0.3945.130, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 79.0.3945.36 (3582db32b3389..., userDataDir: /var/folders/p3/2yjl_8ks615...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:61702}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 37e756b80492ea71b8839b0087072e97
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at com.kms.katalon.selenium.driver.CChromeDriver.execute(CChromeDriver.java:19)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:285)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:106)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$EventFiringWebElement.lambda$new$0(EventFiringWebDriver.java:404)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.sendKeys(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$EventFiringWebElement.sendKeys(EventFiringWebDriver.java:429)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.SendKeysKeyword$_sendKeys_closure1.doCall(SendKeysKeyword.groovy:53)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.SendKeysKeyword$_sendKeys_closure1.call(SendKeysKeyword.groovy)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIKeywordMain.runKeyword(WebUIKeywordMain.groovy:20)
    ... 16 more

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you want to type some text in search field and then hit the enter ? 
After typing text in the search field, use sendKeys method.

```
WebUI.sendKeys(findTestObject('your object goes here'), Keys.chord(Keys.ENTER))
```

But before using this, you need to import following library:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys as Keys
```

Comment: Sadly this dint work for me and somehow magically what i have posted in the question worked the next day . But your solution is what i saw everywhere too